# All Excel files opening as read only

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropbox, microsoft-excel-365

When I open an Excel file from Windows Explorer, if Excel is not already running, the file opens as read only.  I can save it as a file with a new name, but not as the old name (at least not without saving it and renaming it).  I can open files just fine if Excel is already running, either through File > Open or from Windows Explorer.  This problem only happens with .xlsx and .xls files (not with .csv files).

This is on Office 365 on Windows 10.

Things I have tried that have not fixed it:

- The files have "Read Only" unchecked in their permissions
- Explorer preview is off
- I have installed all Office 365 updates
- I have installed all operating system updates
- I have repaired Microsoft Office
- I have restarted my computer
- I have set Dropbox and all of its subfolders as a trusted location in Excel

How do I get Excel files to open as writeable again?

Comment: Have you added the folder location as a trusted location?  Is your system managed by an IT Administrator and/or is the system connected to an AD domain server?

Comment: Opening an Excel file works fine here. In addition to the above comment, are you using a folder that someone else created and restricted permissions?

Comment: @Ramhound setting my Dropbox folder as a trusted location does not work.  My system is managed by just me

Comment: @John The folders are created by the dropbox desktop client.  They do not appear to have restricted permissions

Comment: So are my folders and just ordinary permissions.  Sometimes repairing Office helps, but that does not usually affect permissions on my systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem turned out to be I had a broken add-in, and Excel wasn't booting properly.  When opening Excel from the start menu, it gave me an error dialogue before proceeding to the Excel landing page.  Meanwhile, when opening an Excel file directly from Explorer, Excel skipped the error dialogue and went straight to the file, but couldn't open it in write mode.

Disabling the broken add-in fixed the problem.